# setting wallpaper from resource

Tags: android, wallpaper

I have a simple problem with wallpapermanager and I cannot find the answer on this site.  I have this very simple code with a picture that is 1280x800 (the display of my tablet).  When I run the code, I only get the center of the image as wallpaper, as if the whole picture is zoomed in.  Why is that? Thanks!

```
package com.daniel.wallpaperPorsche;

import java.io.IOException;
import com.daniel.wallpaper.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);

try {
     myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.porsche_911_1280x800_72dpi);

     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Success set as wallpaper", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

} catch (IOException e) {
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error set as wallpaper", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  } 
  super.onDestroy();
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found to set the wallpaper without any zooming issues (which often seem completely arbitrary, as you're seeing when the resolution sizes are the same) is with a BitmapFactory. You'll use WallpaperManager.setBitmap instead of WallpaperManager.setResource.

```
String path = "path/to/desired/wallpaper/file";
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

//The inJustDecodeBounds option tells the decoder to return null (no bitmap), but it does 
//include the size of the image, letting us query for the size.

options.inJustDecodeBounds = true; 
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path_, options);

// Calculate inSampleSize
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, width, height);

// Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
Bitmap decodedSampleBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path_, options);

//wm = WallpaperManager
wm.suggestDesiredDimensions(decodedSampleBitmap.getWidth(), decodedSampleBitmap.getHeight());
wm.setBitmap(decodedSampleBitmap);
```

calculateInSampleSize is a method that Google actually provides an implementation of in the android documentation; their goal is to load large bitmaps efficiently. You can do some reading on it here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Unfortunately, their implementation is crap and frequently wrong. I'd recommend this.

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    int multiplyHeight = 1;
    int multiplyWidth = 1;

    while (imageHeight >= reqHeight)
    {
        multiplyHeight++;
        imageHeight = imageHeight/2;
    }
    while (imageWidth >= reqWidth)
    {
        multiplyWidth++;
        imageWidth = imageWidth/2;
    }

    if (multiplyHeight > multiplyWidth)
        return multiplyHeight;
    else
        return multiplyWidth;

}
```

This method is more efficient for loading large files, prevents an OutOfMemoryException, and should also avoid the strange zooming you're seeing. If not, let me know and I'll take a second look at what I've done.